# Images in grid and description in the center

Tags: html, css, image, grid

I've been looking around here and found several good answers but still didn't get around it. I want to achieve something like [in this image](http://prntscr.com/780pam).

5 small images with each of them has a number above. I tried this but as you can see the numbers were not in center (testing just the first row).

```css
.grid-img {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-img">
<p>1</p>
    <img src="img1" alt="image1">
</div>
<div class="grid-img">
<p>2</p>
    <img src="img2" alt="image2">
</div>
<div class="grid-img">
<p>3</p>
    <img src="img3" alt="image3">
</div
```

Comment: moden browsers, you can try `.grid-img {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
.grid-img p{
position: relative;
left: calc(50%);
}
.grid-img p{
position: relative;
bottom: 2px;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Check this. `text-align: center;` will place the number in center. Insert `<br/>` after the 3rd div. Please see below the updated code.

```css
.grid-img {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-img">
  <p>1</p>
  <img src="img1" alt="image1">
</div>
<div class="grid-img">
  <p>2</p>
  <img src="img2" alt="image2">
</div>
<div class="grid-img">
  <p>3</p>
  <img src="img3" alt="image3">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="grid-img">
  <p>4</p>
  <img src="img1" alt="image1">
</div>
<div class="grid-img">
  <p>5</p>
  <img src="img2" alt="image2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great! How did i not think of it :) Now the questions remains, how can i add two other pictures below as on the picture http://prntscr.com/780pam

Comment: pure genius and yet so simple :) Thank you. I learned alot today! However I do have one more thing, since the images are quite close to eachother at the moment and when using margin-left to increase the gap between images then the descrption: 1,2,3 etc is not in the center of the image anymore when using text-align: center –

Comment: So I figured this one out. Again so simple. Add margin to both sides, left and right. Then the title will keep itself in the center.